# How to Create a Special Navigation Drawer In Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-navigation

I want to create an android navigation drawer like this :

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: Asking for libraries is off-topic for StackOverflow. I'm reverting your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can host a `Fragment` inside `NavigationDrawer`, which means that you can have pretty much any layout in it.

There are no "names" for "types of navigation" - there are just some [guidelines](https://material.google.com/patterns/navigation-drawer.html).

Comment: if this answers your question - consider accepting the answer